# Netcat uploads hanging after a certain point

Tags: linux, bash, netcat, port, hang

I'm working through an introductory cybersec challenge that requires me to upload a word and brute force a 4 digit code to a port. I put the combinations in a file, and tried to use netcat to upload them one at a time. At a certain point (around 6300 uploads) netcat stalled and stopped uploading things. I ended up splitting the list of number in half, but does anyone know why it would do this? My bash script is below for reference (pass blanked out for obvious reasons).

```
pass=xxxx
for i in {0000..9999}
do
    echo $pass' '$i >> options.txt
done

cat options.txt | nc localhost 30002 >> flag &
```

Comment: Are you sure "one at a time" should be interpreted as "one per line during a single connection"? *Maybe* it really is "one line (or one incomplete line) *per connection*". How exactly do you know the problem occurs at "around 6300 uploads"?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I suppose it is possible that it is disconnecting and reconnecting each time. If I connect manually, I can see that the responses leave room for multiple inputs during the same connection. If i wc -l it shows the lines increasing until 6300, each line representing a response to a line of input.